# how to select a value in combo boxes with geb groovy

Tags: groovy, geb

i tried to select a value out of a combo box via groovy(geb).
the html code is:

```
<select id="entity-list-form:statusSearchBtn" name="entity-list-form:statusSearchBtn" size="1" style="width: 200px;">
  <option value="">alle</option>
  <option value="REGISTERED" selected="selected">Wartet auf Bestätigung</option>
  <option value="REJECTED">Registrierung zurückgewiesen</option>
  <option value="APPROVED">Registrierung angenommen</option>
  <option value="UNSUBSCRIBED">Abgemeldet</option>
</select>
```

i tried to access these elements via

```
$("entity-list-form").statusSearchBtn = "alle"
```

or

```
$("entity-list-form").statusSearchBtn.value() == "alle"
```

a different approach was in the page siet to add

```
statusSearchBtn { $('select[name$="entity-list-form:statusSearchBtn"]') }
```

and also the case with the name only like entity-list-form. in this caes i tried it like

```
statusSearchBtn = "alle"
```

or

```
statusSearchBtn.value() == "alle"
```

the last one end without any errors, but didnt change the selected value to "alle".

the former one ended in  `No such property: statusSearchBtn for class: geb.navigator.EmptyNavigator.`

i greatly apprichiate any advice,

Answer (score 1):

I think:

```
$("select", name : "entity-list-form:statusSearchBtn").value('alle')

$("select", name : "entity-list-form:statusSearchBtn").value() = 'alle'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.
i tried your suggestion, it doesnt work. its opening the list of possibilities, but doesnt select one. 
its kind of strange, cause with:
    //print $('select[id$="statusSearchBtn"]').text()
its printing all possebilities. i even can click to open them, but not choose one.

Comment: sorry, i had a click statement before and this one affected your suggestion. its working. thank you.

Comment: may be, i use first example.